# Evaluate a triple integral over a cylinder

Tags: vector-analysis

I have a doubt regarding evaluation of the following triple integral:

$$I=\iiint_V (4xy-2y+8xz) \, dV,$$ where $V$ is first octant of $y^2+z^2=9$ and planes $x=0, x=2$.

Given that the cylinder is symmetrical about $y =0, z=0$ planes and given that $I =\frac{1}{4} $ {volume over given cylinder and given planes } over $(4xy-2y+8xz)$.

As the given cylinder is symmetrical about $y= 0$ and $z=0$, if we put $-y$, $-z$ in $(4xy-2y+8xz)$ we get $(-4xy+2y-8xz)$ which means due to symmetry can I say it is zero.

But if I calculate using cylindrical coordinates I am getting $180$

Can you pls point me to where I am making error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of what the words "first octant" means. The integration limits are not symmetric. Both $y$ and $z$ limits are from $0$ to $3$

Comment: got it i evaluated $\theta : 0$ to $2\pi$, i got zero.

Comment: in cylindrical coordinates, with $\theta$ in the $y-z$ plane, $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\pi/2$

Comment: for whole of cylinder above yz plane,  i evaluated with $\theta: 0 $to$2\pi$, i got zero.

Comment: can you tell me if (1)evaluation is whole of cylinder above yz plane and x=0, x=3,(2) if term is 4yz 

then can i say it is zero??? - if i put -y and with z, i will get -4yz

if i put both -y, -z, then i will get 4yz

pls clarify if integral is zero or not.

Comment: If you evaluate over the whole cylinder, the integral is $0$. Each of the terms is antisymmetric, so an integral over a symmetric range will give $0$.  But you are asked only about the first octant.

Comment: yes i understood what you are saying. this is another doubt here Now say $I=\iiint 4yz$ with **WHOLE** CYCLINDER ABOVE YZ PLANE: AND X=0, X=3. can i say integral zero due to symmetry. if i put -y alone it is -4yz, but if i put both -y, -z, then it is 4yz.

Comment: pls clarify i always get confused here

Comment: Yes. You can do integral for $y$ at any $z$ and you get $0$. Or integrate over $z$ at any $y$ and get the same result